# Understanding Android webview javascript interface

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have created an android `WebView`, and injected `javascript` interface using `addJavascriptInterface(mObject, "jsinterface")`. It works fine until I create an object with same name (jsinterface) in JavaScript using the `new` operator.

## My Java Code:

```
WebView mWebView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient((Activity)mContext));
mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new testClass(), "jsinterface");
mWebView.loadUrl("UrlToLoad");
```

### testClass.java

```
public class testClass{
    public testClass() {
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public String testNativeMethod() {
        return "Java method called!!";
    }
}
```

## My Java Script Code

### test.js

```
function test(msg){
    this.message = msg;

    this.testJSMethod = function(){
        return this.message;
    }
}

alert(jsinterface.testNativeMethod()); // prints Java method called!!
jsinterface= new test("JS method called...");
alert(jsinterface.testJSMethod()); // prints JS method called...
alert(jsinterface.testNativeMethod()); // errors "NPMethod called on non- NPObject"
```

## Problem:

Is this possible for a `javascript` object to have access to both , i.e  `javascript` methods and native `JAVA` methods(exposed to it via `javascriptinterface`) ? Is there any possibility of setting any property to `webview` OR executing any JS `script` to get this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TRY

You may try to make another object, which will retranslate calls to javascript interface.Implement `onPageStarted` method in `WebViewClient` , and inject javascript in `onPageStarted` method, in the following way.

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted (WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            String jsScript= "javascript:var functions_array = ['testNativeMethod'];";
                   jsScript+="var jsinterface = {};"
                   jsScript+="functions_array.map(function(id){"
                   jsScript+="jsinterface[id]= function() {"
                   jsScript+="try{return temp_obj[id].apply(temp_obj, arguments);}"
                   jsScript+="catch(e) { console.log('ERROR: ' + e + ', method ' + id);"
                   jsScript+="return false;}}})"
            view.loadUrl(jsScript);
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 12):

Think about `document` in javascript.  When you are in a web browser, this is a global object that you have access to at any point.  If you make your own `new` var called `document`, you are going to have problems accessing the global `document`.

When you execute this line:

```
    mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new testClass(), "jsinterface");
```

you are adding a global object called `jsinterface`.  This is the same situation as `document`.  If you create a var with the same name, it will overwrite the existing global reference.

Once you add a javascript interface to the `WebView`, you don't need to create a `new` reference to the interface.  `addJavascriptInterface` has already done that for you.